# Função logar não acessa o cadastro, que já foi insirido

Tags: python, login

**Função: Logar e Cadastrar()**

```
def Logar(pessoas):
    from Funções_pt.cores import vermelho
    usuário = str(input('Nome de usuário: ')).strip()
    senha = str(input('Digite sua senha: ')).strip()
    if usuário and senha in pessoas:
        print('Acesso Concedido!')
        pass
    else:
        while True:
            print(f'{vermelho("Acesso Negado!")}')
            usuário = str(input('Nome de usuário: ')).strip()
            senha = str(input('Digite sua senha: ')).strip()
            if usuário and senha in pessoas:
                print('Acesso Concedido!')
                break


def Cadastrar(grupo):
    from Funções_pt.cores import vermelho, amarelo
    nome = str(input('Nome: '))
    if nome.strip() == '':
        while True:
            print(f'{vermelho("ERRO! Por favor, digite sua nome corretamente")}')
            nome = str(input('Nome de usuário: '))
            if nome.strip() != '':
                break
    else:
        pass

    idade = str(input('Idade: '))
    if idade.isnumeric():
        int(idade)
    else:
        while True:
            print('\033[31mERRO! Por favor, digite sua idade corretamente!\033[m')
            idade = str(input('Idade: ')).strip()
            if idade.isnumeric():
                break

    Série = str(input('Série: '))
    if Série.isnumeric():
        int(Série)
    else:
        while True:
            print('\033[31mERRO! Por favor, digite sua série corretamente!\033[m')
            Série = input('Série: ').strip()
            if Série.isnumeric():
                break

    usuario = str(input('Usuário de acesso: ')).strip()
    print(f'{amarelo("ATENÇÃO! A SENHA SÓ PODERÁ SER COMPOSTA DE LETRAS E NÚMEROS, SEM SÍMBOLOS E ESPAÇOS.")}')
    senha = str(input('Senha: ')).strip()
    confirme = str(input('Confirme sua senha: ')).strip()
    while True:
        if senha != confirme:
            print('\033[31mErro de login:\033[m Senhas incorrespondentes!')
            confirme = input('Confirme sua senha: ')
            if confirme == senha:
                break
        else:
            break
    grupo.append((nome, idade, Série, usuario, senha, confirme))
    print('Usuário Cadastrado! Bem vindo ao serviços da School Calculator')
```

**Em seguida coloquei o programa para funcionar:**

```
while True:
    grupos = list()
    sleep(2)
    Menu()
    opc = int(input('Qual sua opção: '))
    if opc == 1:
        Logar(grupos)
    elif opc == 2:
        Cadastrar(grupos)
    elif opc == 3:
        sair()
        break
    else:
        print('Opção inválida! Por favor escreva apenas as opções listadas')
```

**Mas quando executo o login, mesmo cadastrando a pessoa, não consigo acesar, serei grato se alguém puder me ajudar**

Comment: Oi, tente isolar a parte do código que verifica se o usuário está cadastrado, o erro está ali. Fora isso, sugiro que vc melhore a pergunta de forma a perguntar algo bem específico em vez de pedir que alguém analise seu código e ache o erro.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não vou revisar seu código todo, mas recomendo que você salve os dados dos usuários em dicionários, para serem acessíveis por chaves. Assim que cadastrar o usuário, escreva os dados dele um um arquivo `.json` externo. Recomendo esses estudos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3cH8i0ON48  e  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHOoCzvfDHY&t=326s

Comment: Se não souber o que é um dicionário, leia [este](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/trabalhando-com-o-dicionario-no-python) post e bons estudos!

Comment: @Pablo muito obrigado, irei rever o código e organizá-lo. E vou editar a pergunta, desculpe é porque sou novo aqui no Stackoverflow, mas irei colocar de forma clara.

Comment: @yoyo Obrigado, vou colocar em dicionário, ainda pensei em por mais decidir colocar em listas, porque...porque não sei, mas irei reajustá-lo e quanto a pergunta deixarei ela mais clara e objetiva. Obrigado pela ajuda e feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações no código proposto por @LucasV75, sugiro que veja os comentários

```
from time import sleep

grupos = dict()
opções = ["1 - Logar","2 - Cadastrar","3 - Sair"]

def Logar(pessoas):
    usuário = input('Nome de usuário: ').strip()  #Retirei o str(input()) pois o input já é uma string por natureza """
    senha = input('Digite sua senha: ').strip()
    print("-=-"*14)

    if usuário not in pessoas:
        print("Usuário inválido")
        Logar(pessoas)
    
    elif senha != pessoas[usuário]["senha"]:
        print("Senha inválida!")
        Logar(pessoas)
    
    else:
        print('Acesso Concedido!')
    print("-=-"*14)

def Cadastrar(grupo):
    nome = input('Nome: ')
    #if nome.strip() == '':     # para que colocar um if se já temos essa condição dentro de um laço while? 
    while nome.strip() == '':              # aqui fica melhor que a condição esteja dentro do while para reduzir ifs 
        print(f'"ERRO! Por favor, digite sua nome corretamente")')
        nome = input('Nome de usuário: ')  # retirei mais um str(input()), como ja dito, é um exercício de futilidade 
    #if nome.strip() != '':
            #break
    #else:        # não há necessidade de colocar um else: pass, pois se acondição do if não é satisfeita ele naturalmente pula para a instrução seguinte
        #pass

    idade = input('Idade: ')
    if idade.isnumeric():
        int(idade)
    else:
        while True:
            print('\033[31mERRO! Por favor, digite sua idade corretamente!\033[m')
            idade = input('Idade: ').strip()
            if idade.isnumeric():
                int(idade) #esqueceu de adicionar esse passo
                break

    Série = input('Série: ')
    if Série.isnumeric():
        int(Série)
    else:
        while True:
            print('\033[31mERRO! Por favor, digite sua série corretamente!\033[m')
            Série = input('Série: ').strip()
            if Série.isnumeric():
                int(Série)  #esqueceu de adicionar esse passo de novo
                break

    usuario = input('Usuário de acesso: ').strip()
    print(f'("ATENÇÃO! A SENHA SÓ PODERÁ SER COMPOSTA DE LETRAS E NÚMEROS, SEM SÍMBOLOS E ESPAÇOS.")')
    senha = input('Senha: ').strip()
    confirme = input('Confirme sua senha: ').strip()
    while senha != confirme:
        #if senha != confirme:
        print('\033[31mErro de login:\033[m Suas senhas não correspondem!')
        confirme = input('Confirme sua senha: ')
#        if confirme == senha:
#            break
#       else:
#            break   
    grupo.update(
      {
      usuario:{
        "idade":idade,
        "Série":Série,
        "nome":nome,
        "senha":senha,
        }
      }
    )
    print('Usuário Cadastrado! Bem vindo aos serviços da School Calculator')
    print("-=-"*14)



def Menu(grupo):
    for opt in opções:
        print(opt)
    print("-=-"*14)
    opc = int(input('Qual sua opção: '))
    print("-=-"*14)
    if opc == 1:
        Logar(grupo)
    elif opc == 2:
        Cadastrar(grupo)
    elif opc == 3:
        return True
    else:
        print('Opção inválida! Por favor escreva apenas as opções listadas')
    Menu(grupo)
Menu(grupos)
```

O seu código possui diversos `ifs` desnecessários, que exigem processamento sem que seja necessário, recomendo estudar melhor os laços `while` pois você aparenta não saber bem o potencial deles. Deixo ainda as seguintes recomendações:

1. No programa atual, se o usuário por ventura seleciona a opção errada, como por exemplo 'cadastrar' quando na verdade ele queria 'logar', repare que não há como retornar ao menu, ele fica preso até que faça o cadastro, adicione uma opção de retorno
2. Quando o usuário está definindo sua senha, caso a confirmação de senha esteja errada, ele é direcionado para alterar a variável `confirme` e não a variável `senha`. Isso é um problema pois talvez ele tenha errado na hora de preencher a variável `senha`. Nesse caso seu programa não permite mais que ele altere a mesma. Sugiro que quando `senha` e `confirme` não corresponderem, faça o usuário preencher ambas novamente
3. Lembre-se que um `input()` SEMPRE é salvo como string,
   a menos que você o instrua a salvar como outra coisa. O que quer
   dizer que ao fazer `str(input())` você está transformando uma string
   em uma string, e isso não faz sentido

Comment: Obrigado pela paciência e disponibilidade reformatar o código! Ainda estou aprendendo a usar o if não sei 100%, comecei a programar a 5 meses, é meio novo para mim tudo isso, mas quero chegar lá e ser um grande programador. Vou rever e estudar mais a fundo. Muito obrigado pelo apoio.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigi o erro substituindo o list por um dict, testa aí

```
from time import sleep

grupos = dict()
opções = ["1 - Logar","2 - Cadastrar","3 - Sair"]

def Logar(pessoas):
    usuário = str(input('Nome de usuário: ')).strip()
    senha = str(input('Digite sua senha: ')).strip()
    print("-=-"*14)

    if usuário not in pessoas:
        print("Usuário inválido")
        Logar(pessoas)
    
    elif senha != pessoas[usuário]["senha"]:
        print("Senha inválida!")
        Logar(pessoas)
    
    else:
        print('Acesso Concedido!')
    print("-=-"*14)

def Cadastrar(grupo):
    nome = str(input('Nome: '))
    if nome.strip() == '':
        while True:
            print(f'"ERRO! Por favor, digite sua nome corretamente")')
            nome = str(input('Nome de usuário: '))
            if nome.strip() != '':
                break
    else:
        pass

    idade = str(input('Idade: '))
    if idade.isnumeric():
        int(idade)
    else:
        while True:
            print('\033[31mERRO! Por favor, digite sua idade corretamente!\033[m')
            idade = str(input('Idade: ')).strip()
            if idade.isnumeric():
                break

    Série = str(input('Série: '))
    if Série.isnumeric():
        int(Série)
    else:
        while True:
            print('\033[31mERRO! Por favor, digite sua série corretamente!\033[m')
            Série = input('Série: ').strip()
            if Série.isnumeric():
                break

    usuario = str(input('Usuário de acesso: ')).strip()
    print(f'("ATENÇÃO! A SENHA SÓ PODERÁ SER COMPOSTA DE LETRAS E NÚMEROS, SEM SÍMBOLOS E ESPAÇOS.")')
    senha = str(input('Senha: ')).strip()
    confirme = str(input('Confirme sua senha: ')).strip()
    while True:
        if senha != confirme:
            print('\033[31mErro de login:\033[m Suas senhas não correspondem!')
            confirme = input('Confirme sua senha: ')
            if confirme == senha:
                break
        else:
            break
    grupo.update(
      {
      usuario:{
        "idade":idade,
        "Série":Série,
        "nome":nome,
        "senha":senha,
        }
      }
    )
    print('Usuário Cadastrado! Bem vindo aos serviços da School Calculator')
    print("-=-"*14)



def Menu(grupo):
    for opt in opções:
        print(opt)
    print("-=-"*14)
    opc = int(input('Qual sua opção: '))
    print("-=-"*14)
    if opc == 1:
        Logar(grupo)
    elif opc == 2:
        Cadastrar(grupo)
    elif opc == 3:
        return True
    else:
        print('Opção inválida! Por favor escreva apenas as opções listadas')
    Menu(grupo)
Menu(grupos)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas. Estou aprendendo ainda e não pensei que o dict poderia ter melhor resultado. Obrigado pela ajuda!